# Mock a static method taking HttpServletRequest and Principal using Mockito and PowerMock

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, static-methods, powermock

I want to mock a static method taking two parameters, HttpServletRequest and Principal.

```
//Here is the method signature
public static String getRole(HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal)  throws Exception {
}
```

I am defining the security test config for injecting security credentials into the test class.

```
// security test config
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
static class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws    Exception {
         auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password")
        .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

I am writing the junit test case for a method that internally calls the above static method. How to write the expectation for the above static  method in the junit class?

```
when(StaticClassA.getRole(??????, ??????)).thenReturn("ROLE1");
```

Comment: Don't use html tags, SO defines its own formatting tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking static methods with Mockito](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Comment: David, Its not a duplicate.  I did go through the link. I am testing a controller method which takes HttpServletRequest and Principal as the arguments. This method in turn calls a static method by passing these arguments. Is it possible to write expectation for this static call in Mockito/PowerMock?

Comment: have you tried 'doReturn().when()' syntax instead of 'when().thenReturn()' ?